# Reload Tab content using ajax without loading page on Refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax

Reload Tab instead of Whole Page

```html
<div class="content">
    <div id="tabstrip">
        <ul>
            <li id="tabEdit">@ResourceStrings.Text_ProblemDetails</li>
            <li id="tabItemsAffected">@ResourceStrings.Text_ItemsAffected</li>
            <li id="tabAttachments">@ResourceStrings.Text_Attachments</li>

            @if (ApplicationGlobals.SELECTED_COMPANY_CODE != CompanyCode.MONTREAL)
            {
                <li id="tabPlmReferences">@ResourceStrings.Text_PlmReferences</li>
            }

            <li id="tabDispositions">@dispositionsText</li>

            @if (ApplicationGlobals.SELECTED_COMPANY_CODE == CompanyCode.MONTREAL && (ApplicationGlobals.SELECTED_NCRBASE.NcrType != (int)NcrTypeEnum.NCRATTEST))
            {
                <li id="tabReworkDetails">@ResourceStrings.Text_ReworkDetails</li>
            }

            <li id="tabLineClosure">@ResourceStrings.Text_Line_Approval</li>
            <li id="tabTraceability" style="float:right">@ResourceStrings.Text_Traceability</li>
        </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Is it Possible to update parts (Like Tabs) of a web page, without reloading the whole page on switching to another Tab

```js
  $.ajax({
                url: "NcrLine/Reload",
                type: "GET",
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {
                    alert("Hello");
                    
                    var tab = $('#tabstrip').tabs('getSelected');
                    tab.panel('refresh');
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you provide your html structure as well? And what plugin are you using?

Comment: you can use the `load()` of jquery to load the contents of some page to a particular `holder`.

Comment: Using Ajax  ,auto switching to another tab without page refresh

Answer (score 0):

First thing I need to understand is what type of updates are those, if those have simple rendering of code, you can simply bind the HTML code to the tabs handle once you receive the response. This is shown as below -

```
$.ajax({
    url: "NcrLine/Reload",
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function () {
        alert("Hello");

        var tab = $('#tabstrip').tabs('getSelected');
        tab.panel('refresh');

        // Add css to the selected tab
        $('#tabstrip[selected=selected]').css('css-property', 'css-value');

        //Render complete new HTML code of updated tabstrip
        $('#tabstrip').html('<Your tabstrip HTML template>');
    }
});
```

If you have complex HTML rendering, then I would suggest you to create partials by using [handlebars.js](https://handlebarsjs.com/), that will help you to create reusable partials with dynamic values and that can be bind to your content page.

Comment: if i make changes in one tab ex:save and switch to another tab my page is loading its an performance issue so i need to load only tab if i do any changes and i switch to another tab means my entire page should not load only tab must be loaded

Comment: If you are using ajax then there is no point in reloading the page. The other way is to use load method, on which I cannot elaborate much but you could find this helpful.

Create a separate file having your tabs code. You can call that file every time on any of your HTML content tag as -

`$('#tabstrip').load('complete/file/path');`

You can refer the same using below link -

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=reload+a+section+of+page+using+jquery&oq=reload+a+section+of+page+using+jquery&aqs=chrome..69i57.14846j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=1

Comment: I need using asp.net